# SQL / TSQL update value based on all values in column of a sub-query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following tables:

TableA

```
Id    |material |Group
1      pipe      NULL
2      faucet    NULL
3      bracket   NULL
4      beam      NULL
```

TableB

```
TableAId |Program
1         1
1         2
2         3
3         1
3         4
```

I want to update the *Group* column on TableA based on the programs that material is a part of. groups are determined by the programs, such as

> **group1**:      1 || 2 || 1 && 2
>
> **group2**:      3 || 4 || 3 && 4
>
> **commonGroup**: any that exist but don't match above program groups
>
> **noGroup**:     *none*

Desired Result Table

```
Id    |material |Group
1      pipe      group1
2      faucet    group2
3      bracket   commonGroup
4      beam      noGroup
```

Currently I've made a query to give me a table of all the materials and their programs if they exist (if a material has no programs, this places NULL in that column) but I'm having trouble trying to check each row with the same Id to determine what group should be assigned.

```
SELECT
    TableA.Id, TableB.Program 
FROM 
    TableA
FULL JOIN 
    TableB ON TableA.Id = TableB.TableAId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather tricky.  I would recommend calculating the groups in a subquery, and then joining that information back in an `update`:

```
update a
    set group = coalesce(b.grp, 'noGroup')
    from a left join
         (select b.TableAId,
                 (case when sum(case when b.program in (1, 2) then 1 else 0 end) = count(*)
                       then 'group1'
                       when sum(case when b.program in (3, 4) then 1 else 0 end) = count(*)
                       then 'group2'
                       else 'commonGroup'
                  end) as grp
          from b
          group by b.TableAId
         ) b
         on b.TableAId = a.id;
```